# Coded ui - Read/Write values from .csv files

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, coded-ui-tests

I have a codedui test which reads value from an .csv file. I'm using the following code:

```
[DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.CSV", "|DataDirectory|\\testdata.csv", "testdata#csv", DataAccessMethod.Sequential), DeploymentItem("testdata.csv"), TestMethod]

public void test()
{
 String a = TestContext.DataRow["Field 1"].ToString();
}
```

As part of my requirement, i need to capture the test results e.g. id generated and write it back again to "testdata.csv".

I tried using: `TestContext.DataRow["IDField"] = id;`

But its not successful.

My question is:

1. How do we write value to this file during runtime?
2. How to read the above value in a different test?
3. If i need to read values from multiple sources, is there a way to do it because in the datasource, i can give only one file name.

Thanks

Comment: why do you need to capture this value?  Can you just assert a failure if the value is not what is expected and review the test log?  If you are trying to chain tests together, this would not be my recommendation for how to do that.  In my blog, I cover an approach (called Scenarios) for performing actions required for another test to run correctly (eg, setting up preconditions like pending orders, etc).  http://michaelpavlakcoding.blogspot.com/2016/06/decomposing-page-objects.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need to capture this value because i need to pass it to a different test as part of end-to-end scenario. Also the business wants to see the results in the excel sheet rather than as coded ui default output.

Comment: It would not be wise to drive the tests this way.  Your tests should be able to run independent of each other.  if you are able, Microsoft Test Manager can output better reporting around what is passing and failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot update to a CSV data source file that is being read. One approach is to write to a new CSV file. This new file could contain all the data from the data source CSV plus any new fields. The `[ClassInitialize]` or `[AssemblyInitialize]` could be used to write the first line of the CSV with the column titles. The `[TestCleanup]` might be a good place to write the CSV data line as it should be called whether or not the test case passed. If the CSV should be written only for tests that pass then write the CSV data line as the last action of the `[TestMethod]`.

A second test that reads the CSV written as above can be used. Attempting to run both tests at the same time is likely to fail. Having a CSV being read by one test case while another test case is writing lines to it can lead all sorts of problems. (Eg what if the second test catches up with the first, how does it handle reading a file with no data? Do not assume this will work as you would like, assume the worst.)

Coded UI only allows one data source attribute to be given for a test.

Comment: I believe this may work, but I would stress again that this is not a good way to drive your test suites.

Comment: @MPavlak I understand your point but there are cases in testing where the only sensible way of setting up the entry conditions for one test is by using the exit conditions of another. Perhaps for unit test the argument is weak, for UI testing with Coded UI the argument is stronger. For performance testing where thousands of executions of each of several test cases are to be executed it can be necessary to carefully schedule test execution so that data is always available for tests. Some data is loaded before the run, but much of the data is "passed" from one test to another.

Comment: @MPavlak In performance (load) testing you need to consider the database sizes. The test should keep the database at its expected real-world sizes. Generally a test run should not empty the database by consuming all the records, nor should it create so much data that the database is overloaded. Hence a load test may **need** to pass data from one test case to another.

Comment: I do not agree that that is the only sensible way.  There are plenty of ways, in code, to pass around the result of on test into another.  More specifically, you shouldn't pass a test 'result' over, but some artifact that was created during the test.  I have some concepts on my blog http://michaelpavlakcoding.blogspot.com/2016/06/decomposing-page-objects.html around this.  I also use different class hierarchies to enable preconditions to flow.  When setting up preconditions, I do not want assertion to run so I do not want tests to actually run, just setup preconditions.

Comment: I agree about the database thing, to an extent.  The impact of the db should be tested as unit tests and really shouldn't matter for the front end.  Your load test would be against the web server(s), not the database when doing the ui testing (how fast can the server render the page).  The services that call into the database and generate models would be tested separately.

Comment: as an aside, I'm glad to see someone else running around the codedui questions :)  do you have a twitter?

Comment: @AdrianHHH Thanks for your reply. I tried your way by adding multiple data source files by giving multiple [Datasource] attributes but it throws an error stating "Duplicate DataSource and Duplicate TestMethod attribute". Is that something i'm missing in my code? Can you please help me?

Comment: @BalajiVenkatachalam My apologies. I thought Coded UI would accept multiple data sources. Another Visual Studio test type (ie web test) does accept multiples. Answer amended.

Comment: Thanks for all your replies - i managed to create a .csv file and write value to it. I access this value in other tests and pass it as an input value.