# Read/write values from Excel data source file

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, coded-ui-tests

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38140559/2719588), I understand that we cannot update to a CSV data source file that is being read, but by any chance we can update to a **Excel** data source?

```
[TestMethod]
[DataSource("System.Data.Odbc", "Dsn=Excel Files;Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};dbq=|DataDirectory|\\data.xlsx;defaultdir=.;driverid=790;maxbuffersize=2048;pagetimeout=5;readonly=false;", "Sheet1$", DataAccessMethod.Random)]
public void ExcelReadWrite()
{
    String a = TestContext.DataRow["Scenario"].ToString();
    String b = "New Order # generated from the app";
    Console.WriteLine(a + ": " + b);
    TestContext.DataRow["Order#"] = b; //Is this possible? if yes, how to write it back?
}
```

If this cannot work, what approach should I take?
Maybe `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;` or `DataTable`? Going these paths, can we still be able to use `[DataSource]`?

**Update:**
To write to a new file doesn't really work well. The reason is that:

Each Data Source row will be processed in one iteration. The Data Source file will always be the same original copy. Therefore you can update only one row per iteration and you lose the previously updated values.

If you overwrite the new file every iteration, you end up with only one row contains the updated values; if you create different files each iteration, you end up with too many new files, one file only contains one row of updated values, the rest are all the same. For instance if your Data Source file contains 5000 rows, you will create 5000 new files.

Comment: Data driving with data sources has no facilities for writing new values back to the data source. You can achieve similar by writing to a new file, copy the unchanged fields and insert the new values. What is your real problem and why do you think that modifying the values in the data source is required?

Comment: One example would be, say we execute a test with multiple iterations to generate hundreds of orders with the data provided by business to cover different scenarios. We want to write the order numbers and other relevant information on the same data row of the input. We did that with HP UFT before and would like to continue to be able to do so with CodedUI.

Comment: I am fine with your solution just to gather everything together to write to a new file, if there is no way to do this to the original file itself.

Comment: The word in the update are wrong. Data can be written to a new file in append mode, so each iteration write its values to the end of the file. Use something based on `StreamWriter outStream = new StreamWriter("YourOutputFile.csv", true);` where the `true` means append to an existing file.

Comment: If you create a new file by your code either inside the [TestMethod] or [TestInitialize], you end up with a new file each iteration, which of course overwrites data generated from the last iteration. The only thing you can do is to manually create/copy the output file and append to it each iteration. And this will only work for text file, but NOT for an Excel file. Hope my point is expressed clear.

Comment: I will post a solution for Excel as an answer after. It's still ugly but so far I think that is the only way to accomplish what I want. The key points are: 1) You manually make a copy of the Excel Data Source file; 2) Load the whole Worksheet from the copied file in your [TestMethod]; 3) Make changes to data; 4) Write the whole Worksheet back to the copied file. Why is it ugly? Because you read/write the whole Excel Worksheet every iteration. For 1000 rows Data Source, you read/write 1000 times to the copied file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading DataSource and then writing back with updated data will NOT work, because every iteration the test `[TestMethod]` is executed with the *original* Data Source. Updated data from last iteration will be overwritten in each iteration. You end up with only one row of updated data from the very last iteration.

**Solution**:

```
data.xlsx:

Scenario    SecondCol   Result
89          23          Value
11          800         Value
888         111         Value
```

1. load data from Data Source into an Excel.Workbook object
2. update data of the Excel.Workbook
3. overwrite the Data Source file with the updated Excel.Workbook object

The following is an example. `data.xlsx` is the Excel Data Source file.

```
    [TestMethod]
    [DataSource("System.Data.Odbc", "Dsn=Excel Files;Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};dbq=|DataDirectory|\\data.xlsx;defaultdir=.;driverid=790;maxbuffersize=2048;pagetimeout=5;readonly=false", "Sheet1$", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)] // This is working Excel.xlsx connection!!! Excel (ODBC, Dsn)

    public void ExcelReadWrite()
    {
        //Open copied Excel file and create Excel object
        string projectName = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;
        //string dir = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\..\..\..\";
        string dir = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(Environment.CurrentDirectory).Parent.Parent.FullName;
        string targetFilename = "data.xlsx";
        string targetFile = dir + projectName + @"\" + targetFilename;

        object missing = Type.Missing;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(targetFile, true, false);
        Excel.Worksheet ws = wb.Sheets[1];
        Excel.Range wr = ws.UsedRange;
        int rowCount = wr.Rows.Count;
        int colCount = wr.Columns.Count;

        //make some example data update for current iteration 
        int row = TestContext.DataRow.Table.Rows.IndexOf(TestContext.DataRow); //current iteration data row. zero base
        int generatedData = Convert.ToInt32(TestContext.DataRow[0]) + Convert.ToInt32(TestContext.DataRow[1]); //read from DataSource
        ws.Cells[row + 2, 3] = generatedData; //Worksheet, not zero base, and header row counts
        // ======================================================
        excel.DisplayAlerts = false;

        wb.SaveAs(targetFile, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, misValue,
                                             misValue, misValue, misValue,
                                             Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue,
                                             misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
        wb.Close(missing, missing, missing);
        excel.Quit();
    }
```

**Update:**
It is not necessary to make a new copy of the Data Source file. The Data Source file can be updated with `Excel.Workbook.SaveAs` command if you set `readonly=false`. Notice this setting in `[DataSource]` section.

Comment: If you read what I wrote and not what you think I wrote you would realise I said to write to a new file in append mode. Each iteration can append its unchanging input data plus the modified values to a new file. At the end of the run there are then two files, the original and unchanged input file plus a new file with all the new values.

Comment: The key point is that you actually have to work with 2 separate files, regardless if they are identical at the beginning or not. One is for Data Source, which is read only and drives the iterations; the other is the one you read/write/update. For csv file, yes it can be in append mode, but for Excel, you have to overwrite the entire file each iteration.